# Dynamically run Model method with Ajax in C# MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in a Model which takes over 15 seconds to calculate. This occurs multiple times on the same page and is really causing some slowdown. I would like to run this method asynchronously with the page so that the value appears once it is calculated.

Currently this is how the value is called and displayed (within the Index.cshtml view):

```html
<div><a href='@item.LinkToJiraByStatus("Blocked")' target="_blank">Blocked</a>: @item.GetNumJiraIssuesByStatus("Blocked")</div>
<div><a href='@item.LinkToJiraByStatus("Open")' target="_blank">Open</a>: @item.GetNumJiraIssuesByStatus("Open")</div>
```

I would like the @item.GetNumJiraIssuesByStatus (both Open and Blocked) to be done with Ajax. Here is the method within the Model:

```html
 public int GetNumJiraIssuesByStatus(string status)
        {
            var sJql = "project = \"" + JiraProjectKey + "\" and status = " + status;

            //apply a 'result field' filter simply to reduce the amount of data being returned. Any field will do - use of 'resolution' is entirely arbitrary.
            var resultFieldNames = new List<string> {"resolution"};

            Issues issues = new JiraClient(new JiraAccount()).GetIssuesByJql(sJql, 0, 1000, resultFieldNames);

            return issues.total;
        }
```

I have been trying to instead get this done by having a span which populates with the value when the AJAX is done:

```html
 $(".jiradata").each(function (i, el) {
                    var $el = $(this);
                    $.get("/Project", { s: "open" }, function (data) { text; })
                })
```

Although this does not work properly. Does anyone know what I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: `$.get("/Project?status=open", function(....` seems more legit to me. On the other hand you don't do anything with the ajax response

Comment: No luck unfortunately, there is no value appearing at all in between the span.
This is what is now in the view:  <div><a href='@item.LinkToJiraByStatus("Open")' target="_blank">Open</a>: <span data-jira="jira-open-@item.Id" class="jiradata"></span></div>

Comment: In the callback, you need to tell the JS the output the value in this span

Comment: Isn't that what the text; bit does? I assumed it would populate the span since the function does a get? Sorry I'm relatively new to Ajax calls.

Comment: No, `text` alone means nothing. You might need `$el.text(data)`